# How to show a div what was hidden on img

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, visible

So I have to make a hidden element (div) visible when you click on an image. 
It worked on a button, but I can't seem to make it work on an image.

HTML code:

```
<div id="img4">
   <img src="images/nummer1.png" alt="nummer1" data-hint="1"/>
</div>      

<div id="hint" class="hidden">Hint 1</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';


    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var hint = document.getElementById("hint");

var showHint = function (event) {
    console.log(this);
     if data-hint === '1'
     hint1.classList.toggle('hidden');
    };

var img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    console.log(img);

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("click", showHint);
    };

function show(hint) {
    };

button.addEventListener('click', show);
```

---

You see? It works on the button, but for some reason I can't make it work on an Image.

Comment: what specifically do you mean when you say you *can't make it work on an Image*? are you getting any errors? does absolutely nothing happen? For one, I see a bunch of missing curly braces and parens in the code you pasted...

Comment: fiddle of the illustration would be nice and fiddle can easily point out your syntax flaws

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wnqV8/ checkout the errors you should see this before go finding answers error in javascript syntax is a big chink in the armour of programmer

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're not using jQuery.  You might want to look into it, as it would make what you're trying to implement easier and much more readable.

But in any event:

```
hint1.classList.toggle('hidden');
```

Should be

```
hint.classList.toggle('hidden');
```

Also,

```
if data-hint === '1'
```

Needs to be

```
if (this.dataset.hint == 1)
```

which is how you check the `data-hint` attribute of `this` element (the one that was clicked).

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/t46ws/

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $("div").show();
});
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should update the hints id:s so for every image there are a corresponding hint, which shares the same id. So the first hint got a id of "hint-1".

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .show {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>

    <div id="img4">
        <img src="/test/img2.jpg" alt="nummer1" data-hint="1"/>
    </div>

    <div id="hint-1" class="hidden">Hint 1</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");


            for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
                images[i].onclick = function() {
                    var that = this;
                    var id = that.getAttribute("data-hint");
                    var hint = document.getElementById("hint-" + id);
                    hint.className = "show";
                };
            }



        };


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
var showHint = function (event) {
    console.log(this);
    if(typeOf(hint) != 'null') hint.classList.toggle('hidden');        
};
```